# Why is select faster than a function call?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a STABLE function `get_value_by_id(id)` which just gets the value from table indexed by `id`.
I run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on function and also on the same `SELECT` statement which is inside function.

```
SELECT * FROM table where id = $id.
```

Total runtime for `SELECT` is always better. Why is that ? 
Should avoid using functions for this kind of situations ?

EDIT:

Adding result of the explain analyze :

```
"Function Scan on get_value_by_id  (cost=0.25..0.26 rows=1 width=1640) (actual time=0.187..0.189 rows=1 loops=1)" 
"Total runtime: 0.231 ms"
```

```
"Index Scan using id_index on table  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=255) (actual time=0.023..0.026 rows=1 loops=1)" 
"  Index Cond: (id = 10000)" 
"Total runtime: 0.073 ms"
```

**EDIT2** Adding the function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_value_by_id(my_id integer)
  RETURNS table1 AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
  result table1;
BEGIN
    SELECT val1, val2, val3 INTO result
        FROM table1
        WHERE id  = my_id;

RETURN result;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION get_value_by_id(integer)
  OWNER TO my_user;
```

Results with SQL function :

```
"Function Scan on get_value_by_id_sql  (cost=0.25..0.26 rows=1 width=1640) (actual time=0.324..0.326 rows=1 loops=1)" 
"Total runtime: 0.421 ms"
```

Comment: Why do you need a function for a single select statement?

Comment: Please show us the execution plans (or upload them to http://explain.depesz.com)

Comment: @juergend I thought it would be faster since it caches the execution plan.

Comment: Perhaps you should show the function too ?

Comment: @nos please see the updated quoestion.

Comment: You don't need a PL/pgSQL function here. A simple `SQL` function will be enough and should probably be faster. You can also check if changing the `ROWS` parameter to 1 changes anything. Btw: why did you declare it as `returns table` if you are clearly returning only a single row?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Let me try with ROWS 1. Actually it is just table name. BTW if I will switch to SQL then execution plan will not be cached again

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it says "ROWS is not applicable when function does not return a set". This makes sense since I am return a 'record'. So ROWS = 1 by definition

Comment: Ah I overlooked that it says `table1` not `table`. But still you might try a SQL function, rather than a plpgsql.

Comment: I want to check is it still faster when I have millions of records.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually it is even slower with SQL function... this is very bizarre

Answer (score -1):

"User defined functions in any language are going to be slower than using the equivalent inline logic; it adds more processing instructions and overhead to the overall algorithm and more processing = more slower." [source](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/964-sql-user-defined-functions-are-slower-than-inline-logic.htm)

Comment: That article is about SQL Server, not about Postgres.

Comment: Yes, the source is about SQL, but the quote that was taken from it applies to this question directly.

Comment: The article isn't about "SQL" it's about **SQL Server**. And SQL Server has a completely different concept regarding functions (it e.g. does not have different languages in which functions can be implemented).